# infinite parent-child node list

Tags: php, mysql

I wasnt sure what to label this so here we go.

I have a table which holds messages sent by users. The first message sent is the parent and then each message after that is a reply. However a reply can have a reply, and a reply to a reply can also have a reply...and so on. The table structure is:

```
message_id   message   reply_messages_id
1            abc       0 (this means its the parent)
2            def       1 (reply to message_id 1)
3            ghi       2 (reply to message_id 2)
4            jkl       1 (another reply to message_id 1)
5            mno       3 (reply to message_id 3)
6            pqr       0 (another parent)
7            stu       6 (reply to message_id 6)
```

The thing I am struggling with is that I am trying to have the output displayed as:

```
abc
- def
  - ghi
    - mno
- jkl
pqr
- stu
```

The other thing is I dont know how many layers deep a reply can go as a user can keep replying to replies.

ANY help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215980/categories-with-sub-php-mysql/10244518#10244518

Comment: What you need simple recursion to build your output. Possible duplicate of [Recursive function to generate multidimensional array from database result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result)

Comment: @Kere Puki - Thanks..  This is same type using menu script.. http://hiox.org/33272-php-db-based-menu-script.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I litterally just answered one similar to this about a week ago... it generates the output as a stored procedure including indentation...  The principles would be almost identical, just slight change in the column names of data.

[Other answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688608/mysql-output-in-tree-format-or-adding-level-parent-child/10774455#10774455)